# Page Navigation in Sencha Touch?

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch

I am new to Sencha Touch, and wonder how page navigation works.
so far, the best i found was something like:

```
    var redirect = 'page2.html'; 
    window.location = redirect;
```

and to prevent unnecessary fetching, cache all .js and style using app.manifest.

Any recommendation? Is there a way similar to page navigation in JQuery mobile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Sencha Touch does not support page navigation the way jQuery mobile does.

If you really have to redirect (and make a page refresh), then I believe the only way of doing it is the way you have described (window.location).

However, in Sencha Touch, there is often no need to do redirects. You could easy create a fullscreen Panel, and then change the content of this panel dynamically (i.e. navigate to a page). Have a look at one of the examples, to get the idea:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/oreilly/

Comment: Nico is correct - one of the main reasons to use Sencha Touch is that you have a single page-load at the start and then you dynamically update page contents from AJAX calls. That way you avoid laggy, and user jarring page refreshes.

Comment: Yes, using panels is a good option. in fact each sub-panel can be considered an equivalent to a page in JQuery; which can be changed dynamically at runtime.

Comment: ok... you're saying it can be changed dynamically at runtime.... how? Isn't this the original question? to change the first-page