# how to navigate page in sencha touch2?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new in sencha touch and i am refer [this project](https://github.com/nelstrom/Sencha-Touch-tabs-and-toolbars-demo) for learning purpose.
In this project, i am trying to add login module, if login is successful then the other things is display (which is already in project).

I made changes in `app.js` file and load login form(this is worked).
`app.js :`

```
ToolbarDemo = new Ext.Application({
    name: "ToolbarDemo",

    launch: function() {
        this.views.Home = new this.views.Home();
        //this.views.viewport = new this.views.Viewport();
        //this.views.homecard = this.views.viewport.getComponent('home');
    }
});
```

and In `Home.js`, i create login screen and if username is not blank i want to redirect it to `Viewport.js` which contain other pages.

I try some things which is commented in if blocks.

`Home.js :`

```
ToolbarDemo.views.Home = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
    fullscreen: true,
    title: 'Login',
    cls:'Loginscreen',
    id:'loginFormPanel',
    items: 
        [
        {
            html: '<div align="center"><img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" src="stylesheets/images/main-logo.png" /></div>'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            items: [
                {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name : 'name',
                            id:'name',
                            placeHolder : 'User Name',
                },{
                            xtype: 'passwordfield',
                            name : 'password',
                            placeHolder : 'Password',
                }
           ]
        },
        {
                xtype:  'button',
                text:   'Login',
                cls:'LogingButton',
                ui:     'confirm',
                itemId:'loginbutton',
                handler: function() {
                    var name = Ext.getCmp('name').getValue();
                    //var pass = Ext.getCmp('password').getValue();
                    if(name != '')
                    {
                        //ToolbarDemo.app.switchMainView('ToolbarDemo.view.Viewport');
                        //Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('ToolbarDemo.view.Viewport'));
                        //this.redirectTo('Viewport');
                        //var firststep = Ext.create('ToolbarDemo.view.Viewport');
                        //Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(firststep);
                        /*ToolbarDemo = new Ext.Application({
                             name: "ToolbarDemo",
                        launch: function() {
                            this.views.viewport = new this.views.Viewport();
                            this.views.homecard = this.views.viewport.getComponent('home');
                        }
                        });*/
                        alert("aa");
                    }
                }
        }
        ],
    });
```

`Viewport.js :`

```
ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
    fullscreen: true,
    xtype: 'viewport',

    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            tabBar: {
                dock: 'bottom',
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center'
                }
            },
            items: [
                { xtype: 'homecard', id: 'home' },
                { xtype: 'searchcard' },
                { xtype: 'actioncard' },
                { xtype: 'logincard' },
                { xtype: 'settingscard' },
                { xtype: 'morecard' }
            ]
        });
        ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

so how  to navigate the page? I am try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800671/sencha-touch-redirect-to-another-view) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754849/page-navigation-in-sencha-touch) but it is not helped.

`another quetion:`

I am also refer other tutorials and also the official website of sencha in which they use `controller,model and view`  type patterns and in my project there is no `controller`.

so which types of coding format should i follow that helped me to understand senchatouch?

Is my project is good for practice?

I refer diff. tutorials and i become confused. so what shoud  i do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the 4th point - **Animate and activate containers from a common function** from this article [Sencha Touch coding guidelines you should follow: Part 1](http://innofied.com/sencha-touch-coding-guidelines-you-should-follow-part-1/) and you will understand how to do this. We generally have a common function in our Utility class that takes care of page navigation.

Regarding Sencha Touch practice, it seems you still lack some understanding. You should find a good book and spend some time understanding the basic concepts. Here is a good tutorial on how to create a Sencha Touch app: [How to Create a Sencha Touch 2 App](http://miamicoder.com/sencha-touch-tutorials/)

If you want an advanced tutorial, here is a thorough tutorial that provides a step-by-step app development process:

1. [Create a Location-Aware Site with Sencha Touch](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/create-a-location-aware-site-with-sencha-touch/)
2. [Create a Location-Aware Site with Sencha Touch – Displaying Locations](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/create-a-location-aware-site-with-sencha-touch-displaying-locations/)

Comment: any suggestion for book?

Comment: @DS9: I think the tutorials which Swarnendu has shared are very good. Why are you asking for book, just go through this.